# TypeError: conv2d() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have an error here

```
tf.compat.v1.layers.conv2d(filters = 32,kernel_size = 7,strides = 2)
```

the error is

```
TypeError: conv2d() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

and I can not find any argument in this function called inputs
could you help me?

Comment: A single line of code is meaningless without context, please add more code to see where this line fits.

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/conv2d) to see how this function is used. I would also recommend not using outdated interfaces, but `tf.keras` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per Dr Snoopy it is difficult to know what the problem is with only 1 line of code. But I will take a stab at it. If you are using the Model API then your line of code should have the form

```
tf.compat.v1.layers.conv2d(filters = 32,kernel_size = 7,strides = 2)(x)
```

where x is the input to the layer. For example if the above code is the first layer then you should proceed it with

```
x=tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224)) # or whatever the input shape is
```

Comment: This won't work because they are not using keras, but the outdated `tf.layers` interface instead.